# what's contain ${Session.resources} in applicationContext?

Tags: spring

i'm trying to understand this applicationContex:

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Definició dels beans de sessió i usuari -->
**<import resource="${session.resources}" />**

<!-- Definició dels beans del subjecte anònim -->
${session.subjecteanonim}

<!-- Integració amb BASE OnLine -->
<import resource="classpath:bf-modul-baseonline-appConfiguration.xml" />

<import resource="classpath:gim.logica-context.xml" />
```

```
<!-- Serveis de lògica de negoci proporcionats per base 
<jee:remote-slsb id="serveiMestreMunicipiEns"
        business-interface="cat.base.mestres.servei.IServeiMestreMunicipiEns"
        jndi-name="${cat.base.mestre.municipi.ens.service.name}">
    <jee:environment>
        java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
        java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
        java.naming.provider.url=${cat.base.mestre.municipi.ens.jndi.url}
        java.naming.provider.port=${cat.base.mestre.municipi.ens.jndi.port}
    </jee:environment>
</jee:remote-slsb>
```

-->

so, my problem is that I don't know where is defined ${session.resources}, and what can i have inside? is from jsf?I hope you apologize for my strnge english, ty.
ztb.

this is the parent's pom: 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>cat.base</groupId>
<artifactId>gim</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
   <groupId>cat.base.baseframe</groupId>
   <artifactId>projecte-pare-baseframe</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.11.a</version>
</parent>

<modules>
    <module>gim.assistent</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cat.base</groupId>
        <artifactId>mme.domini</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and this i the pom's application

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>cat.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>gim</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>gim.assistent</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Assistent d'Expedients GIM</name>


<build>
    <finalName>gim.assistent.${profile.entorn}</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>./</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>change.log</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!--  domini, servei deps. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb3x</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.ga</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-ejb3</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossall-client</artifactId>
        <version>EAP-4.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- test deps. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
        <artifactId>ifxjdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.JC2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!--  ui deps. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.js</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.binding</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2_10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>




<!-- PERFILS DE CONSTRUCCIÓ -->
<profiles>

    <!-- PERFIL CIUTADA -->
   <profile>
        <id>ciutada</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/applicationContext.xml</include>
                                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <profile.entorn>ciutada</profile.entorn>
            <session.resources>classpath:bf-modul-session-bd-jbosscache-appConfiguration.xml</session.resources>
            <session.postproces>classpath*:bf-modul-session-bd.properties</session.postproces>
            <session.subjecteanonim>
                <![CDATA[
                <import resource="classpath:bf-modul-subjecte-anonim-appConfiguration.xml" />
                ]]>
            </session.subjecteanonim>
            <webxml.module.filter>cat.base.baseframe.modules.login.session.bd.BaseSessionLoginJBossCacheFilter</webxml.module.filter>
            <webxml.module.listener>cat.base.baseframe.modules.login.session.bd.BaseSessionHttpSessionEventListener</webxml.module.listener>
            <webxml.login.config>
                <![CDATA[
                <login-config>
                    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
                </login-config>
                ]]>
            </webxml.login.config>
            <webxml.subjecte.anonim.filter>
                <![CDATA[
                <filter>
                    <filter-name>SubjecteAnonimFilter</filter-name>
                    <filter-class>cat.base.baseframe.modules.anonim.filtre.SubjecteAnonimFilter</filter-class>
                    <init-param>
                        <param-name>acceptaAnonims</param-name>
                        <param-value>false</param-value>
                    </init-param>
                </filter>
                <filter-mapping>
                    <filter-name>SubjecteAnonimFilter</filter-name>
                    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                </filter-mapping>
                <listener>
                    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
                </listener>
                ]]>
            </webxml.subjecte.anonim.filter>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <!-- PERFIL EMPLEAT -->
   <profile>
        <id>empleat</id>
        <activation>
          <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/applicationContext.xml</include>
                                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <profile.entorn>empleat</profile.entorn>
            <session.resources>classpath*:bf-modul-session-ldap-jbosscache-appConfiguration.xml</session.resources>
            <session.postproces>classpath*:bf-modul-session-ldap.properties</session.postproces>
            <session.subjecteanonim/>
            <webxml.module.filter>cat.base.baseframe.modules.login.session.ldap.BaseSessionLoginJBossCacheFilter</webxml.module.filter>
            <webxml.module.listener>cat.base.baseframe.modules.login.session.ldap.BaseSessionHttpSessionEventListener</webxml.module.listener>
            <webxml.login.config>
                <![CDATA[
                <login-config>
                    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
                    <realm-name>BaseRealm</realm-name>
                    <form-login-config>
                        <form-login-page>/security/login-page.jsp</form-login-page>
                        <form-error-page>/security/login-error.jsp</form-error-page>
                    </form-login-config>
                </login-config>
                ]]>
            </webxml.login.config>
            <webxml.subjecte.anonim.filter />
        </properties>
    </profile>
 </profiles>
```

Comment: it seems `${session.resources}` is a property stored in a property file. do you have any property file and can you post more from application context configuration including possible property configurations.

Comment: I was looking for in the property files, and i couldn't find, maybe is and object from the flow?

Comment: can you search _session.resources_ in the project? it may be seen in the search result. you can use file search.

Comment: sorry by the delay...there no results...and ty for your time. I carry on searching!

Comment: what happens if you remove it? can you trace the console logs for it?

Comment: seems to work perfectly...it's sth about session bean and users doesn't it?

Comment: i think you copied configuration from else where and some files are missing. Just remove it if it works.

Comment: i didn't copy anything, i'm just trying to understand to make some changes, but ty a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ! i find a way to understand! 
this variables are defined at pom anf do reference to maven profile a way to aunthenticate.

```
   <session.resources>classpath:bf-modul-session-bd-jbosscacheappConfiguration.xml</session.resources>
```

I felt like a stupid monkey.
ztb